# Obtain EXIF data from Photos uploaded from IOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, exif

We have a requirement to obtain EXIF(i.e. Created date,Camera Make, Software Version, Geolocation) data from the photos taken & uploaded through IOS device , but due to security restrictions the EXIF data is stripped off from the photos,

Please suggest us any workaround for this ,So we could obtain the EXIF data from the photos uploaded into a website from any IOS Devices?

Thanks & Regards,
B

Answer (score 0):

If the Exif data has been removed from the file, there is no way to get it back from that file. You would need to look at the process by which these images were modified and try to obtain the days before it is removed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But we'd be able to obtain the photo only after the specific photo has been uploaded in the URL, So obtaining the metadata before is not possible from the webpage.

Comment: In this case it doesn't sound like there anything you can do then. But you know more and may come up with a creative solution. Good luck.